# Getting IE and Firefox errors: Error in parsing value 'xxx'. Declaration dropped

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a link to my page: http://myweb.students.wwu.edu/~tuckerb2/cs202/peanuts/project/open.html. I'm having trouble with all browsers, though it works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. I need to fix this parsing error that shows up in Firefox and IE so that it will a) not show an error in Fox and b) actually work in IE. Please help! Thank you!

Comment: It works for me in Firefox 12 and IE9. I am not seeing any errors.

Comment: I never installed ie9, now doing so...

Comment: @BrianTucker you are missing out, just got myself VMs going to get a somewhat native feel for IE6, IE7 and IE8..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things going on that you should have a look at

Firsly, in IE (6,7,8) window.innerHeight doesn't exist, instead you could use the below which will:

```
var h = (document.documentElement.clientHeight/2)-17;
```

The other issue is that once the letters match up in the center of the screen you do not stop the timers you have started. This means they will keep running and generate errors as the variables topLetters and bottomLetters are now larger than the size of the arrays topPos and bottomPos.

The function setInterval returns a reference to its timer, so you could then use the following code

```
var topTimer, bottomTimer;
function startSnowing() {
    topTimer = setInterval("topFall()",10);
    bottomTimer = setInterval("bottomRise()",10);
 }
```

and change your topFall() and bottomRise() methods to something like

```
function bottomRise() {
    if (bottomLetters < bottomPos.length) {
        document.getElementById("bottomLetters").style.bottom = bottomPos[bottomLetters] + "px";
        bottomLetters++;
    }
    else {
        clearInterval(bottomTimer);
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps!